# Why would I get a JSON error when I try to rake db:migrate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rubygems

When I try to run `rake db:migrate` I keep getting this error:

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- JSON
```

Has anyone else come across this problem, if so how did you solve it?

I have tried a lot of different things already. I tried adding the gem 'json_pure' to the Gemfile after doing some googling. I also tried checking out to previous branches that I know I was not getting this error. Kind of stuck now. Let me know if anyone can help me out.

The error is actually not happening on my friend's mac. It is happening on Heroku and on my linux computer.

Comment: Please, run your task with `-t` or `--trace` key so show us more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a play with irb:

```
irb(main):002:0> require 'JSON'
LoadError: no such file to load -- JSON
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from (irb):2
        from /home/mslade/rubygems1.9/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):003:0> require 'json'
=> true
```

So there is a 'json' module, but no 'JSON' module.

When a migration runs it pulls in most/all of your rails setup as well.  If you have a `require 'JSON'` somewhere in your code that you added into a module that hasn't yet been tested.

Comment: It was working on the mac because case insensitivity. On heroku and my ubuntu machine it was not wokring. the lowercase made everything work.